# Javascript object modification

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an javascript object in structure

```
var data = {
    "items": [
        {
            "User": {
                "first_name": "Testing",
                "last_name" : "test",
                "age" : 23
                }
            },
            {
            "User": {
                "first_name": "Testing_2",
                "last_name" : "test_tested",
                "age": 24

                }
            },
            {
            "User": {
                "first_name": "Testing_3",
                "last_name" : "test_test",
                "age" : 23
            }
        }
    ]
};
```

I am trying to modify the object structure as,
sample output:

```
var data = [
    [
        {
            "User": {
                "first_name": "Testing",
                "last_name" : "test",
                "age" : 23
            }
        },
        {
            "User": {
                "first_name": "Testing_3",
                "last_name" : "test_test",
                "age" : 23
            }
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "User": {
                "first_name": "Testing_2",
                "last_name" : "test_tested",
                "age": 24
            }
        }                    
    ]
];
```

**Logic**: I am trying to group the users based on the age. But I am going some where wrong in my logic, please suggest me where am I going wrong or with any simple logic to achieve the required solution.

```
items = data.items;
var user = [], out= [];
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    var dt = items[i].User.age,
        index = user.indexOf(dt);
    if (index == -1) {
        user.push(dt);
        out.push(new Array(items[i]));
    } 
    out[index].push(items[i]);  
}
return out;
```

Please help me.

Comment: `TypeError: out[index] is undefined`. Here you are the error.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined, this is the error i am getting @MarcosPérezGude

Comment: I get the sorting of users by age, but why do you want an object to turn into an array of arrays?

Comment: i am trying show entries with same age in a individual div, i thought by using array i can get the index and push the entries by age

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insert your items into buckets in an empty array that are indexed by `age`. Filter out the empty buckets, and you'll have what you want.

```
var results = [];
data.items.forEach(function (item) {
  results[item.User.age] = results[item.User.age] || [];
  results[item.User.age].push(item);
});

return results.filter(function (res) { return res; });
```

Comment: You are unnecessary increasing  array size by `results[item.User.age]`, `results` is an `array` not a `object`, the way you are treating.

Comment: @JagsSparrow Well technically, `results` IS an object :). And I know `results` is an `Array`; that's why I used `Array#filter`. You can index into an array just as you can in an object, just not with named indexes. Since we can use `User.age` naturally as a numbered index, I thought an `Array` would be just as easy to deal with since that was our desired end result. I do agree that I'm unnecessarily increasing array size though. This isn't the most time/space efficient; worst case being if all users are of large ages.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an object as a hashtable for the reference to the result array.

This solution runs in one loop only.

```js
var data = { "items": [{ "User": { "first_name": "Testing", "last_name": "test", "age": 23 } }, { "User": { "first_name": "Testing_2", "last_name": "test_tested", "age": 24 } }, { "User": { "first_name": "Testing_3", "last_name": "test_test", "age": 23 } }] },
    grouped = [];

data.items.forEach(function (a) {
    if(!this[a.User.age]) {
        this[a.User.age]=[];
        grouped.push(this[a.User.age]);
    }
    this[a.User.age].push(a);
}, Object.create(null));    

console.log(grouped);
```

Comment: thank you for your solution, I got one doubt from your answer why u have used Object.create(null) any particular reason?

Comment: the `Object.create(null)` creates an really empty object, without any property or prototype of `object`.

Answer (score 2):

You can group based on `age` using `.reduce` fucntion

```
var output = data.items.reduce(function(result,obj){
    result[obj.User.age] =  result[obj.User.age] || []
  result[obj.User.age].push(obj);
  return result
},{});
```

instead of `array` we can use `object` as it will be easier to manipulate.

If you want strictly array then we can modify as below

```
Object.keys(output).map(function(x){
  return output[x];
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add **else** in your condition :

```
items = data.items;
var user = [], out= [];
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    var dt = items[i].User.age,
        index = user.indexOf(dt);
    if (index == -1) {
        user.push(dt);
        out.push(new Array(items[i]));
    } else {
        out[index].push(items[i]);
    }  
}
return out;
```

Check this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/s9RZkhM43VUs7hwtONZW?p=preview)